# Jenkins CI - SSL CA error

Tags: azure, tomcat, ssl, jenkins, bitnami

> **NOTE:** This is .NET Core on Linux (Ubuntu)

I am setting up some CI infrastructure for .NET Core code and am running into a strange issue. Specifically, when it comes to package restore ([`dotnet restore`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/dotnet-restore)).

The Jenkins instance that I am running is hosted on Azure via a [Bitnami Jenkins image](https://wiki.bitnami.com/Applications/BitNami_Jenkins). In my build, I have a number of build steps. One of them (the one that actually triggers `dotnet restore`) is an **Execute Shell**.

When I run `whoami` from it, I get that I am the user `tomcat`. When `dotnet restore` is triggered from within the build step, however, I get the following error:

```
06:22:37 log  : Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.runtime.serialization.primitives/index.json'.
06:22:37 log  : An error occurred while sending the request.
06:22:37 log  :   Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)
```

That same issue does not happen if I SSH into the box and do a `sudo su - tomcat` - running `dotnet restore` on the same folder from a SSH session works, while doesn't work in the **Execute Shell** step (despite the fact that both run in the same user context).

What am I missing that might be causing this?

Comment: can nuget restore be tried instead?

Comment: @Aravind why `nuget restore` instead of `dotnet restore`?

Comment: both are going to restore the missing reference packages. Since that option did not work I thought you may try the nuget option.

Comment: @Aravind don't think `nuget` is actually bundled as part of the SDK on Linux?

Comment: oh okay. I did not realise that this dot net core running on linux..

Comment: Hi, Bitnami developer here,

I'm sorry, but I'm not able to reproduce the issue. I just followed these steps:

- Launch the Bitnami Jenkins image from the Azure launchpad.
- Install `dotnet` and make an app using `dotnet new`
- Build a new job with `dotnet restore` but the job finished without issues.

Could you please provide us some steps in order to reproduce it? For sure I'm missing something.

Comment: @FranciscoOrtiz - try cloning the dotnet/core-docs repo from GitHub and then try `dotnet restore` on some of the projects there. I can share the script with you separately that I use to find all `global.json` and `project.json` files.

Comment: @DenDelimarsky I'm experiencing a similar issue, did you find a solution to the error of dotnet on Linux?