# Upgrading Microsoft.AspNetCore.All resulted in "SSL CA cert" and "NuGet" error

Tags: .net, ubuntu, jenkins, ssl-certificate

I'm using a build server to run `dotnet publish` on my .NET project to package the project and the dependencies.

When I run `dotnet publish` using

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.6" />
```

in my .csproj file, the application runs dotnet publish as expected.  However, when I make the change to increment the AspNetCore version to `Version="2.0.7"` it results in a:

```
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.104/NuGet.targets(104,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. 
[/{file-path}/dotnetproj.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.104/NuGet.targets(104,5): error :   An error occurred while sending the request. 
[/{file-path}/dotnetproj.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.104/NuGet.targets(104,5): error :   Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?) 
[/{file-path}/dotnetproj.csproj]
```

(This is an example, if I make any modifications to the packages listed in the .csproj file, e.g. add a new package, it results in the same errors.) . I'm running this command through Jenkins.

Is there a way for me to correctly run the incremented version? Does it involve updating / recreating certificates for the build server? The server is running ubuntu.

Any help on this issue will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thank you @TarunLalwani for pointing that out - that was a typo.  I've updated the question.

Comment: Instead of changing it this way, can you do a `dotnet remove ...` and then `dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.All --version 2.0.7`. Manual modification may not be the right way to doing it

Comment: Okay, I'll take a look at the modules installed on the Jenkins .NET.  I'll deleting the workspace before each build, but this probably isn't removing the installed packages?

Comment: @TarunLalwani I did a remove of the package, and an add of the package to be added from the command line. But I still got the same errors appearing.

Answer (score 0):

That seems similar to "[Jenkins CI - SSL CA error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38736096/6309)" and its associated [`dotnet/cli` issue 3987](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3987) (without any answer)

Check your Jenkins agent (I assume  Linux one): see:

- [bug 221538](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=221538) (about `security/ca_root_nss` being installed), or
- "[Git and Curl SSL Certificates Configuration](http://derekmolloy.ie/fixing-git-and-curl-certificates-problem-on-beaglebone-blac/)": make sure the package **`ca-certificates`** is up-to-date.

Both depends on OS where the Jenkins agent is running.